DataStax Cassandra Java Driver 4.14.x withSSLContext JDK root cert
Currently, I'm connecting my spring boot application to CassandraDB via SSL using the truststore file and password that are hardcoded in application.properties file. Due to security issue, I'm trying to use the JDK root cert instead of the truststore file. The official manual states that sslContext is optional (https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.14/manual/core/ssl/index.html); however, I must pass the sslContext. Otherwise, a compile error will happen.
CqlSessionBuilder builder = CqlSession.builder()
                .addContactPoints(addressList)
                .withLocalDatacenter(localDataCenterProp)
                .withKeyspace(keyspaceName)
                .withAuthCredentials(username, password)
                .withSSLContext(sslContext); // sslContext here is not an optional. Skipping it will lead to a compile error.

Can you please advise on how I can establish the SSL connection without manually passing the sslContext?
Thanks!
